# Modifying a cross join query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

I have this query that I found that I want to modify in order to get an extra column and also sum the last 3 months of the amounts found. I want to make a Crystal Report for this.
Query below.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Tax_year, 
    dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Employee_ID, 
    SUM(dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Amount) AS PAYE, 
    dbo.OADM.CompnyName, 
    dbo.OADM.CompnyAddr, 
    dbo.OADM.TaxIdNum, 
    dbo.OHEM.lastName + ', ' + ISNULL(dbo.OHEM.middleName, '') + ' ' + 
        ISNULL(dbo.OHEM.firstName, '') AS EmployeeName, dbo.OHEM.govID

FROM dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA] 
        INNER JOIN dbo.OHEM ON dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Employee_ID 
                                           = dbo.OHEM.empID CROSS JOIN dbo.OADM
WHERE (dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_PD_code = 'SYS033')

GROUP BY 
    dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Tax_year, 
    dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Employee_ID, 
    dbo.OADM.CompnyName, 
    dbo.OADM.CompnyAddr, 
    dbo.OADM.TaxIdNum, 
    dbo.OHEM.lastName, 
    dbo.OHEM.firstName, 
    dbo.OHEM.middleName, 
    dbo.OHEM.govID
```

The table `OHEM` contains an alphanumeric field called `U_Process_month` that has characters from January to December. As the query is as above, the `SUM(dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Amount)` gives the totals for all PAYE amounts, `ie. U_PD_code = 'SYS033'`.

I would like to have a query that adds up the last 3 months (PAYE) based on a year and month selected.

I would also like to retrieve and extra column, `SUM(dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Amount) as TAXABLEPAY where (dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_PD_code = 'SYS034')`.

How do I achieve this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results on them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wasn't sure what datatype U_Tax_year was so I left it as INT.  However, this query should return the 3 months previous to the month you set.

```
DECLARE @start_month DATETIME;
DECLARE @start_year INT;

SET @start_month = '2013-04-01';
SET @start_year = 2013;

SELECT dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Tax_year
     , dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Employee_ID
     , SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_PD_code = 'SYS033' THEN dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS PAYE
     , SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_PD_code = 'SYS034' THEN dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS TAXABLEPAY
     , dbo.OADM.CompnyName
     , dbo.OADM.CompnyAddr
     , dbo.OADM.TaxIdNum
     , dbo.OHEM.lastName + ', ' + ISNULL(dbo.OHEM.middleName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.OHEM.firstName, '') AS EmployeeName
     , dbo.OHEM.govID
  FROM dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA]INNER JOIN dbo.OHEM ON dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Employee_ID = dbo.OHEM.empID CROSS JOIN dbo.OADM
 WHERE dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_PD_code IN ('SYS033', 'SYS034')
   AND dbo.OHEM.U_Process_month IN (DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH,-3, @start_month)), DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH,-2, @start_month)), DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH,-1, @start_month)))
   AND dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Tax_year = @start_year
 GROUP BY dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Tax_year
     , dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Employee_ID
     , dbo.OADM.CompnyName
     , dbo.OADM.CompnyAddr
     , dbo.OADM.TaxIdNum
     , dbo.OHEM.lastName
     , dbo.OHEM.firstName
     , dbo.OHEM.middleName
     , dbo.OHEM.govID;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-- You can sum up columns based on filters by using a case
SUM(CASE    WHEN U_PD_code = 'SYS033' THEN dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Amount 
            ELSE 0) AS PAYE, 
SUM(CASE    WHEN U_PD_code = 'SYS034' THEN dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Amount 
            ELSE 0) AS PAYE2, 

-- Obviously your WHERE becomes
WHERE (dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_PD_code IN ('SYS033','SYS034'))

-- Your month year fitler can be added to your where like this..
-- You can convert month to a date and then use BETWEEN a month parameeter, and 2 months back (3 months total)
-- Note I assumed month name for your param, change to number if needed. You gave no info on year so I assumed it was as shown.
AND MONTH(U_Process_month + ' 1 2010') BETWEEN MONTH(@YourMonth + ' 1 2010') AND MONTH(@YourMonth + ' 1 2010') - 2
AND dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Tax_year = @YourYear
```